# scroll-margin-top not working on mail layout

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, templates

In my Angular app, I have a Admin Template page layout as shown on the following image:

[image: layout]

I set `.content-wrapper`, `body` and `html` as shown below:

```
html, body { 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;  
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  scroll-margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Here is the layout in my `app.component.html`:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

There is a problem related to the top of the scrollbar. As shown on the image, it seems to be under header from the bottom point of the header. I just tried to set `scroll-margin-top` in order to move the top of scrollbar to the bottom point of the header. But it does not make any sense.

What is a proper way to fix this problem?

Comment: try to play with 'display' property of your .content-wrapper, otherwise a stackblitz could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution is to use the inline-flex display attribute and set the side width to 70vw minus 10px and the right area to 30vw minus 14.4px.

```css
html, body { 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

header, footer {
  border:1px solid black;
  height:20px;
}

aside {
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-flex;
  width:calc(70vw - 10px);
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}

.content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  display:inline-flex;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:calc(30vw - 14.4px);
}
```

```html
<header>&nbsp;</header>
<aside>&nbsp;</aside>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<footer>&nbsp;</footer>
```